# Is Delta E a reliable guide to the difference between colors?

Tags: colors, color-space

I'm attempting to order some color swatches by "maximum difference" and am getting some odd results. For example, in the image below, colors numbers 5 and 14 appear, at least to my (non-colorblind) eye, rather similar, much more so than some of the following colors, but yet seem to have a higher minimum ΔE (when calculated against all the *previous* colors) than many of those colors that follow it.

Is ΔE considered a reliable way of calculating a "perceptual distance" between colors, or should I be using something else?

In order, the colors shown here are:

```
> x.hex
 [1] "#060186" "#8EF905" "#F5C5F7" "#805200" "#0DE0FE" "#D0135D" "#0B834F" "#FABF74" "#417BEA" "#FA4D01"
[11] "#DC39FC" "#590708" "#919913" "#01DDAE" "#068896" "#D28B8B" "#7C4C8E" "#A3BCE7" "#0C5378" "#F1E11E"
[21] "#A24731" "#495C0D" "#01B633" "#4A30FE" "#BB7D0A" "#680F41" "#C1D597" "#FC75C1" "#A786C7" "#29A4DD"
[31] "#FD0A3D" "#43A99B" "#B16A8D" "#D002A2" "#BA7755" "#FECBB6" "#253467" "#FF9143" "#8A763A" "#5960A6"
[41] "#B79D66" "#70A271"
```

And the minimum ΔE against the previous colors:

```
> DeList
 [1] 117.25473  69.53788  55.00019  46.90173  38.54371  37.20359  36.32807  35.23608  28.57360  27.10889
[11]  26.77178  25.24130  24.39958  24.24133  22.51525  22.23315  20.50791  19.93881  19.63842  19.45253
[21]  19.31200  19.04087  18.90102  18.64973  18.25806  18.08846  17.55115  17.19687  16.82420  15.35578
[31]  15.17018  14.95605  14.77414  14.67706  14.67703  14.37527  14.16665  14.02716  14.00375  13.90574
[41]  13.84133
```

I'm calculating ΔE using the R package spacesXYZ, using the formula:

```
spacesXYZ::DeltaE( lab.matrix[i,], lab.matrix[j,], 2000 )
```

and calculating the hex code from the LAB matrix using:

```
x <- lab.matrix[pal.list,]  # extract the LAB numbers from the matrix
x.lab <- colorspace::LAB(x) # convert to an LAB colorspace class
(x.hex <- colorspace::hex(x.lab)) # convert to hex string
```

[image]

Comment: How do you calculate Delta E? There are many formulas for delta E. In any case all formulas works only for similar colours. Else it tell you the colours are different but not comparable with colour differences of other pair of colours. So, with delta E > 5 (some people use also 2), just set it as "much different", without extra meaning of the value)

Comment: Hello @GiacomoCatenazzi.  Not sure I really understand your reply, I'm afraid, further than I write in the Q: "I'm calculating ΔE using the R package spacesXYZ, using the formula: spacesXYZ::DeltaE( lab.matrix[i,], lab.matrix[j,], 2000 )", which uses the CIE 2000 metric, described by its author as "For metric=2000 the distance is insanely complicated".  I'm not attempting to tell if the colors are the same, but order them by "maximum distinguishability".  In this case the subject colors are more similar than other pairs with lower ΔE.

Comment: So you are using CIEDE2000. Only small values of DE are valid and comparable each other. Your DE values are too high (>10), so they cannot be used to compare each others. I think we are still away from such target. And it is also not the main use of DE. Usually it is used as tolerance (when you requires a product on certain colour), so usually with values less then 2.0

Comment: Many thanks. I wonder then if the 1976 metric -- euclidean distance -- might serve me better?  My initial tests did use that but were not particularly satisfactory either, though for reasons I didn't record.  Is it worth calculating distance in LCH space rather than LAB?

Comment: No. CIEDE2000 is very good, and it is practically an Euclidian distance of LCh colour space, with an additional correction factor). It is just that all of them sucks on huge colour differences (and psychology has also an impact). There are other way to check e.g. contrasts. And if you are going in such details, then all colour blindness factors are taken into account. A can of worms.

Comment: How would you go about calculating colour contrast?